# Google Spreadsheet (Display the past year)

Tags: google-sheets

I am familiar with the `=Today()` function in Google Spreadsheets. I have it stored in a cell as the "end date" for a report I am creating.

Wondering if there is a function that would let me display the past exactly 1 year back from my "end date" eg. `=Today()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it..pretty cool:

EDATE(start_date, months)

I used =EDATE(F5, -12)

f5 is =Today()

Now showing two dates...365 day

https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&ctx=tooltip

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following formula to accomplish that:

`=DATE(YEAR(A1)-1;MONTH(A1);DAY(A1))`

as the `EDATE` function is limited to months.